# git not restoring file structure when switching back to original branch

Tags: git

I checked out a branch that had a completely different file structure. I tested some changes and switched back to my dev branch. When I switched back, the same file structure remained. When I look at the git log on my dev branch they match exactly of those that are on the online repo (branch was not merged into dev).

Did I corrupt my git files somehow? I was also working on a different branch and now the file structure when switching to that branch has also changed to the first and my changes are lost.

For the moment I have just cloned the repo again into a different folder, but it would be very nice to use the existing repo and reclaim my changes on my working branch.

Comment: Do you see empty directories?

Comment: Ah, actually didn't even notice that, but yes directories are empty!

Comment: `git` only tracks files, not directories. When you switch "back", the files are deleted, but the directories remain.

Comment: ahh.. you're absolutely right.. that's quite confusing behavior. Is there a way to get the project directory back to it's original state when switching branches?

Comment: @C-Otto That doesn't sound completely right to me.  I don't recall having to do big cleanup operations every time I change branches.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I also agree with you, but to verify @C-Otto’s response I created a test git repo, created two folders with files, made an initial commit, switched to a new branch, created a new folder, switched back to original branch, and the new folder was now a part of the master branch. I’ve been using git for many years but it’s the first time I’ve noticed this..

Comment: @GovindRai I'm undeleting my answer, because I don't think this is limited to folders, it happens with files too.  The answer to your question is don't switch branches if your working directory is dirty, do a reset first, or commit, or maybe stash.

Comment: @GovindRai Note that the "new folder" in your example is **not** part of the master branch because you never committed it. As mentioned earlier, git only tracks files, not folders. What I think you meant is that the new folder still exists in the working directory when you switch to the master branch.

Comment: To address your original question, what is the state of the working directory at each stage in this process? At any point do you have local changes (including new files) which have not been committed?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that is correct. I'm amazed I didn't hit this exact scenario until now.. I suppose it is just the case that I just never noticed a dangling folder or two in event I created new folders in a feature branch (this one was quite apparent because there were 15 new folders introduced in the feature branch).

Comment: @GovindRai If you create new files in those new folders and commit them, changing to another branch should completely remove the new folders along with the files they contain. The only reason I can think of the folders remaining in the working directory is if the new files contain additional changes which have not yet been committed.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice You're absolutely right. In fact I verified that with another test repo yesterday. However, what is really strange is the problematic branch I was working on was pulled down from our online repo meaning everything was being tracked and committed, but it still left "ghost" directories on the main branch. That is super strange.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you switch branches with a dirty working directory/stage, those changes will be carried over to the other branch.  The solution here to have consistent behavior is to not switch branches with a non empty working directory.  But the bigger question is if you tested some changes, what was your ultimate intention for those changes?  If you do not want those changes, you can just reset the test branch and then checkout the original branch.  If you do want those changes, then consider making a commit or a stash.  So the solution I am proposing is that you not checkout the original with a dirty working directory/stage.